# Filter Posts form API in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

i create a Vue App where i want to show up some posts and filter them by an input field.

First of all, i tried to store the data in a constant and create the filter logic.

Afterwards, i add axios and fetch data from an API. This doesn't work and i think it's because of the life cycle hook of vue.

I tried serveral options but the data will not show up in my App.

So how do i implement the API or the data in my VUE that the filter works?

```
<template class="bg-white">
  <div class="w-full">
    
    <div class="pb-8 pt-4">
      <input type="text" v-model="keyword" placeholder="Search for..." class="p-4 border border-gray-500 font-light xmy-4 w-full" />
    </div>

    <div v-for="(post, index) of filterPosts" :key="index">
      <img :src="post.url" />
      <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'ExampleFilter',
  props: {
    col: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      keyword: '',
      posts: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filterPosts() {
      const { posts, keyword } = this
      return posts.filter(({ title }) => title.includes(keyword))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadPosts() {
      let self = this
      this.$axios
        .get('http://localhost/test/wp-json/posts/v1/object')
        .then(function (response) {
          self.posts = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadPosts()
  },
}
</script>
```

Edit:

Thanks for the answers so far. I updated the code but my filter don't show any items

Comment: Your `filterImages` returns the filtered array of `images`, based on value of `keyword`. When you make your call, you place the result in `posts`. Since you're not using `posts` anywhere in `<template>`, why are you expecting it to make any difference?

Comment: You did not use posts in your template, you just fetched the posts.

Comment: It looks like posts has nothing to do with this.  The v-for refers to filterImages and filterImages refers to the images array and keyword.  Are you saying it works differently if you don't do the axios get?

Comment: yes i didn't use the value because it will not work.. in my example above only the images value work.. if i create an console.log the return value of posts is still empty

Comment: Okay, it's confusing because the axios code looks like it's trying to initialize posts, but your workaround initializes images. Why don't you edit the question to expose the code *want to have working*, but *isn't currently working*.  (also, include @username in comments if you want them to see stuff after they've navigated away)

Comment: @danh i have update the code which i want to working in my app.. the "posts" value is still empty and i don't know whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

I suspect -- from the test data in your prior edit -- you have post url mixed up with some image url buried deeper in the post data. As proof that the problem lies elsewhere, see the following snippet. You can find posts by inputting (case-sensitive) text that appears in the titles...

```js
function pretendAxios() {
  const data = [{
      url: 'some url A',
      description: 'description A',
      title: 'Strawberry Fields Forever'
    },
    {
      url: 'some url B',
      description: 'description B',
      title: 'In My Life'
    },
    {
      url: 'some url C',
      description: 'description C',
      title: 'I Want To Hold Your Hand'
    },
  ];
  return Promise.resolve({
    data
  })
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      keyword: '',
      posts: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filterPosts() {
      const {
        posts,
        keyword
      } = this
      return posts.filter(({
        title
      }) => title.includes(keyword))
    }
  },

  methods: {
    loadPosts() {
      let self = this
      pretendAxios()
        //.get('http://localhost/test/wp-json/posts/v1/object')
        .then(function(response) {
          self.posts = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.loadPosts()
  },
})
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">

    <div class="pb-8 pt-4">
      <input type="text" v-model="keyword" placeholder="Type a case sensitive title word" class="p-4 border border-gray-500 font-light xmy-4 w-full" />
    </div>
    <div v-for="(post, index) of filterPosts" :key="index">
      <p>{{ post.title }}, {{ post.url }}, {{ post.description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that the use of "self" in `loadPosts()` is unnecessary.